# Changing the properties of an object on one list also affects objects on another list

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of objects called *foodList*. I also have another list called *historyList*. If I add an object from *foodList* to *historyList*, and later modify one property of this object inside *historyList*, it also changes the property of the object inside *foodList*.

```
val food = foodList[index]
Log.d(TAG, "foodList old id: ${food.id}")
historyList.add(food)
historyList[0].id = Random.nextDouble()
Log.d(TAG, "foodList new id: ${food.id}")
Log.d(TAG, "historyList new id: ${historyList[0].id}")
```

Output:

```
foodList old id: 0.38091249782516334
foodList new id: 0.6356768572458605
historyList new id: 0.6356768572458605
```

I'm lost, why does this happen, and how to stop it? The point of *historyList* in my App is to have a copy of some objects from *foodList*, but with a different ID so it doesn't create conflict in some parts of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental principle of object oriented programming. When you pass an instance of class around and assign it to different variables or put it into different collections, you are not copying the whole class. You are copying references (aka pointers in other languages) to the same instance of that class. They are pointing at the same object in memory.

Kotlin does not have structs, which *are* copied when passed around in languages that support them. (It does have inline classes which are immutable and can be optimized by the compiler to be copied instead of having a reference passed, but that's an optimization and doesn't change the way you have to think about them.)

Kotlin provides the `data` keyword for classes, and if you use it, then the class will have a `copy` function that can create a true copy. To get the behavior you're wanting, you should define the class as a `data class` and use `copy` when putting it in the other list.

```
data class Food(val id: Double, /* ... */)

val food = foodList[index]
Log.d(TAG, "foodList old id: ${food.id}")
historyList.add(food.copy(id = Random.nextDouble())
Log.d(TAG, "foodList new id: ${food.id}")
Log.d(TAG, "historyList new id: ${historyList[0].id}")
```

Side note, you should not use floating point numbers (Float/Double) as an ID because equality comparison of floating point numbers is error-prone.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's all clear now. It was already a data class so it was easier to make the code changes. About floating numbers as an ID, what is a better way to do generate unique ID's?

Comment: Simplest is to use a Long and start at 1, incrementing by 1 for each new value needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the food Object to historyList, what you did was pass-by-reference.  Hence historyList has access to the same "memory address" of the Object food.